# Printing big-length string not showing all chars

Tags: c, string, char, printf

I want to concatenate lots of strings together to produce a unique string which will be long enough. Here is an example code:

```
 char *s;
 s= strconcat("A big-length string",NULL);
 fprintf(stdout,"%s",s);`
```

When I try to print it, the string is less that is printed is smaller than the actual string.
Assume that the `strconcat()` function works well. Do I have to `malloc()` some space for `s`??

Also when I try `strlen(s)` it shows me the right number like 1078. just the printing is the matter.

**EDIT**
The problem solved when after all strings I try to inject `\n` like this

`s= strconcat("A big-length string","\n",NULL);`

Comment: If we can assume that the `strconcat` function works well, we can also assume that it does the memory allocation (and that you have to `free(s)` after printing it). How can we solve your problem if you (a) don't show us the crucial code and (b) don't provide the real data for the code?

Comment: `strconcat()` is not a standard function. We do **not** know what it does. Do you have the source for it, to show it here? Do you probably mean `strcat()`.

Comment: What does the `strconcat` function do, exactly?

Comment: [The strconcat() returns a string with dynamically allocated memory](http://manned.org/strconcat.1). So you don't have to use `malloc()` here.

Comment: `char *strconcat(char *first,char *second, ..., NULL)` The concat just joins strings together...

Comment: If `strlen` shows the right length, then `fprintf` is the cause of the error. Try adding `\n` after the string, that could help

Comment: Agreed with @alk you should use `strcat()` instead, but this way you will have to manage your memory.

Comment: @JML The function you linked doesn't seem to require a `NULL` at the end (making it impossible to be implemented portably), so I don't think it's the same one.

Comment: @interjay Perhaps not the good manual page, but it's the first Google result when I'm searching for `man strconcat`.

Comment: You need to post a **complete**, compilable example that demonstrates the problem, including a `main` function and the `strconcat` function. This question cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: @JML What I'm saying is that OP probably has his own implementation of `strconcat` that you won't find on Google, and we won't know what it does without seeing it. What you linked seems to be a FreeBSD-only function.

Comment: @ThomasRuiz That was the problem!!! Solved. Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: Or to not spoil the "string", just so: `fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",s);`

Comment: @alk this does not work for me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Comment: @KonKost: You want to say appending a `"\n"` to the buffer and printing it shows all characters, but **not** appending a `'\n'` and doing `fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", s)`does **not** show all characters?

Comment: @KonKost, Klas Lindbäck answered it nicely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output using printf/fprintf is usually buffered.

If the output file is connected to a terminal, output is line buffered, so the buffer will be flushed wfter each `\n`.

If the output file is not connected to a terminal, output is fully buffered, so the buffer will be flushed when it is full. Typical buffer sizes is 1kb-8kb.

to ensure that the buffer is flushed call:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

You can flush all file buffers with:

```
fflush(NULL);
```